# Probability problem (Bayes)

Tags: probability, statistics

I don't understand this exercise. How can I solve this problem?

> A worker takes the subway to work 70% of the time. In this case she gets to work on time with a probability of 85%. On average she only gets to work on time with a probability of 60%. Today the worker arrives punctually for work. What is the probability that she used the subway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Let us write some symbols:
$$
S=\{\text{take the subway}\},P(S)=0.7\\
T=\{\text{get to work on time}\},P(T|S)=0.85\\
$$
Also we know $P(T)=0.6$.

Now Bayes' theorem states:
$$
P(T)\,P(S|T)=P(S)\,P(T|S)
$$
and they are asking you to solve for $P(S|T)$.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this without using Bayes' formula by applying the conditions to a hypothetical number of cases, for example 1000 cases.
 The worker takes the subway to work $700$ times and gets to work on time $595$ times (you can easily calculate this by yourself). She goes to work on foot $300$ times. We know that she is punctual $60$% of the time, so the probability that she used subway is $\frac{595}{600}\times{100} \approx 99.16$%.

Comment: Exactly Bayes' theorem without the name :)

Comment: Yes, in general :)